# another exponential distribution probability example

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

I have an exponential variable with $\mu = 169$ hours which represents time to failure for a part in a machine.  I know that the probability that it will last for 100 hours or less is about 0.45.

Given that the part has been used for 100 hours, what is the probability that it will last for 100 more?  I think the memoryless principle applies here, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: The answer depends on the physics involved.  Is the part wearing out for example.  Memoryless principle would not apply.

Comment: This has nothing to do with physics.  The whole incorporation of the physics (of wearing out) is captured in the exponential distribution itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bayes' rule:

$$P(t>200 | t>100) = \frac{P(t>200) P(t>100 | t>200)}{P(t>100)}$$

where I think the notation is rather straightforward and of course $P(t>100 | t>200) = 1$.

Perhaps this figure will help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be an exponential random variable. The memoryless property says that $$ P(X > t+s | X >s) = P(X>t) $$ for any $t\geq 0$ and $s \geq 0$. Recall that the vertical bar "$|$" in the probability statement here can be read as "given" or "conditional on". In your question, we have both $t=100$ and $s=100$. Can you figure it out from here?